# How to get named list when reading multiple csv files from given folder?

Tags: r, list, csv

Assume I have several csv files in given folder, When I read them, I could have unnamed list where each list element has default numeric index. How can I read them as named list instead ? Here is my code what I've done:

Regarding the reproducible data, it is allowed to use public dataset

```
  file <- list.files(folder, full.names = TRUE, "\\.csv$")

  f.read <- lapply(1:length(file), function(ele_) {
    res <- as(read.csv(file[ele_]), "data.frame")
    res
  })
```

I am expecting to have named list instead of default unnamed list, how can I get easily my expected output? Any idea ?

my desired output would be :
after I read cvs files from given folder, each list element must have specific name instead of default numeric index. 
How can I get my expected output easily? Does anyone know possible way getting this output? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `setNames` with the extracted file names (with `basename` and `file_path_sans_ext`)

```
setNames(lapply(file, read.csv), tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(file)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can pass a named vector into `lapply`:

```
f.read <- lapply(setNames(file, tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(file))), read.csv)
```